# Changing route in Angular causes re-evaluation of functions on the previous route's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute

I've a got a route (e.g. `/items`) and its controller has

```
$scope.pathForItem = function (item) {...}
```

method, which is used in the template to display path for each item in a list. When I'm on this page and I click any link to change the route, Angular calls `$rootScope.$apply()` somewhere in its code and that causes re-evaluation of some of functions defined on `$scope`. The problem is that this re-evaluates functions on scope of the previous route's controller as well, thus calling `pathForItem` again once for every item on the page. Usually it's not a big issue - it's unnecessary, but doesn't cause any errors.

However, it causes errors when I try to sign out. `pathForItem` assumes that `user` object exists (which it gets from `authService`) and it usually works, because we ensure that user exists in this route's `resolve` function. Now, when one tries to sign out, Angular calls `$rootScope.$apply()` and tries to call `pathForItem` for all items again. However, somewhere in the middle, the user gets finally removed, `authService.currentUser()` starts returning `null` and all further calls to `pathForItem` raise an error...

Should it really work like that? Should Angular's `$rootScope.$apply` call functions for the controller of the previous route as well? Is there some generic workaround or do I have to make sure that all functions in all controllers that are also used in templates, always check if all objects they use are actually there, even though I've already checked it in `resolve` function?

I'm using Angular 1.3.10 with ngRoute.

Comment: `$apply` doesn't know anything about routes. How should it? I'd rather be concerned that a function is called during every digest cycle. That doesn't seem to be a particularly idea.

Comment: Well it's hard to avoid it. Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/B4sH8bZhRJmRdTP4UWGt?p=preview If you click "Second" link, Angular still calls "first()" - check console output. Also, I have no idea why it calls it 3 times, but that's another issue.

Comment: Ideally `pathForItem` is a value, not a function. I don't know your situation, of course, but I don't think that the return value of `pathForItem` changes with every digest cycle. I get the impression that it depends on the logged in user, that means the value doesn't change at all.

Comment: Yeah, I could use one-time binding to avoid it, but I still think that it's really strange that I need to worry about such stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function in an (interpolation-)expression is called during every digest cycle and you can't possibly know in advance when this will happen. So your function has to be prepared to be called not only more often then you expect but also at unexpected times.

The culprit in your case is the html5 mode. There is a global event handler that rewrites links and calls `$apply`. The problem is that it's done even if html5 mode is not enabled. I consider this a bug because the docs say

> When html5Mode is **enabled**, enables/disables url rewriting for relative links

Anyway, you can turn this behavior off in a config block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({rewriteLinks: false});
```

See the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.0/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#html5Mode) for more information. If you need this behavior then you either prepare your function for your situation or make `$scope.pathForItem` a value. I recommend the latter one anyway.

Comment: Thanks. As `pathForItem` returns a different value for each item, I think it's better to use one-time binding - this should also easily handle cases when items array is modified.